# Did not find a network ACL that is associated with the Private Subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

I created a private subnet and network ACL then I edited the inbound, outbound rule to allow all traffic that goes into and out of the Private Subnet but I am getting errors

**Error**

**Did not find a network ACL that is associated with the Private Subnet. Make sure that you associated the network ACL with the Private Subnet.**

Any clue to solve this problem? Please help

Answer (score 0):

Here is a blog that covers this topic in detail:
https://cloudacademy.com/blog/aws-network-acl-vpc-subnets-network-security/

When you create the ACL, you specify inbound or outbound in the tab:
[image: Inbound or Outbound]

When you then enter the ACL, the Source is going to be the Subnet you wish to target:

[image: Edit the Source]

Comment: thanks for your reply I will look into this link.